# Нужна ли запятая между сказуемыми, выраженными разными частями речи?

Tags: пунктуация

Я ранняя пташка и всегда встаю [здесь продолжение предложения].

Answer (score 1):

Я ранняя пташка и всегда встаю....

1) Предложения с однородными сказуемыми занимают **среднее положение** между сложным предложением и предложением с однородными членами. **Чем больше спаянность сказуемых, тем они ближе к однородному ряду.** Однородные сказуемые имеют одинаковое морфологическое выражение, контактно расположены, не распространены, имеют общий второстепенный член и т.д.  Определенную роль играют **и средства связи**. Так, бессоюзная связь или наличие соединительных союзов **способствуют  спаянности сказуемых.**

Материал взят из учебника Г. И. Кустова "Синтаксис русского языка".

2) **Из других источников**

Вопрос о классификации предложений с несколькими сказуемыми не имеет однозначного решения. Одни исследователи называют такие предложения сложными, другие относят к простым, третьи усматривают в данных конструкциях признаки и простого, и сложного предложения, в зависимости от способа выражения сказуемых.

Включение в предложение группы сказуемых приводит к осложнению его предикативной основы. **Происходит осложнение видовременного плана: между сказуемыми возникают отношения одновременности, или последовательности, или причинно-следственные, что поддерживается и видовыми значениями.** Такие синтаксические отношения совпадают с отношениями в сложносочиненном предложении. [Вопрос о предложении с однородными сказуемыми. Их соотношение со сложными предложениями | refleader.ru](http://refleader.ru/jgejgeyfs.html)

3) Надо отметить, что хотя грамматический анализ предложений с однородными сказуемыми не всегда однозначен, **это мало отражается на пунктуации**. Дело в том, что при наличии **одиночного соединительного союза** ЗАПЯТАЯ ОБЫЧНО СТАВИТСЯ в любом случае, а сказуемые **приравниваются к однородным,** даже если присутствуют признаки их неоднородности.

Comment: Кто-то ставит плюс, кто-то минус, а я хотел бы знать истину (которая, как известно, рождается в споре). Плюс не требует аргументации, а вот почему минус - хотелось бы знать.

Comment: Потому что "сложное предложение" здесь высосано из пальца, его и в помине нет. Запятая, естественно, не нужна. Не случайно никаких ссылок и в помине нет – чистая отсебятина.

Comment: У филологов есть проблема: как различить подобные предложения, а вот у Niemand проблем нет, у него всё просто-примитивно, всё уровень 5 класса и прошедшего века. И всех остальных он призывает к тому же. Кроме того, уважаемый Niemand, меня утомила ваша просторечная кухонная лексика,  уважайте общество хотя бы немного, пока просто прошу.

Comment: Это не отсебятина, вот ссылка : http://scicenter.online/sintaksis/odnorodnyie-glavnyie-chlenyi-126266.html

Comment: Предложения с разнооформленными сказуемыми (глагольные и именные) чаще всего считают не простыми с однородными сказуемыми, а сложными с односоставными простыми, следовательно, запятая нужна. Это переходный тип предложений, автор вправе выбрать, какими их считать и ставить ли запятую.

Comment: Sibylla, я так и не поняла, как Вы считаете, нужна или нет запятая. И как понять:"... при наличии одиночного соединительного союза ЗАПЯТАЯ ОБЫЧНО СТАВИТСЯ в любом случае" ? Если однородные члены - не ставится, если ССП - ставится, не ставится, если есть общий член, восклицательный или вопросительный знак, если предложения назывные. У нас таких условий нет.

Comment: Людмила, я эту тему еще раз просмотрела, и мне кажется, что запятую при наличии союза И лучше не ставить (этот вариант встречается чаще). Просто УСЛОВНО считается, что это однородные члены, а не сложное предложение, иначе возникают сложности с пунктуацией, да и на школьном уровне  эта тема не изучается.   Хотя сказуемые выражены различным образом, союз И  отчасти сближает их. В общем,  тема  актуальна для вузовского анализа, причем  при наличии противительных или разделительных союзов, а тогда и пунктуация для сложного и осложненного предложения одна и та же. Мне так кажется.

Comment: Что касается приведенного примера,  то там присутствует пауза, которая характерна для сложного предложения. И конструкция  близка скорее к сложному предложению, но реально в подобных случаях запятая не ставится. Их предпочитают считать осложненными, а не сложными, а другую  точку зрения доказать не так просто.

Answer (score 0):

Примечание: В некоторый момент в вопросе стояло предложение "**Я ранняя пташка и всегда встаю чуть свет**". Я на него ответил. Затем в вопрос были внесены изменения. А ответ я решил оставить (вдруг кому-то будет интересен).

По смыслу, союз "и" здесь вообще не уместен. Вторая часть уточняет/объясняет первую. Если поставить союз "и", то получится плеоназм. Уместны запятая, тире и двоеточие.

Я ранняя пташка, всегда встаю чуть свет.

Я ранняя пташка - всегда встаю чуть свет.

Я ранняя пташка: всегда встаю чуть свет.

Comment: А почему союз *и* неуместен?

Comment: @Aer  По моему мнению, союз "и' неуместен потому, что вторая часть уточняет/объясняет первую. Если поставить союз "и", то  получится плеоназм. (Как, скажем, "я веселый и всегда веселюсь")

Comment: В результате некорректной правки был искажен исходный смысл предложения. Я внес некоторые изменения в вопрос. Пожалуйста, обратите на них внимание.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, стоит признать, что **запятая здесь как минимум необязательная**.

Все зависит от того, к какому типу предложений причислять данное, считать его простім с однородными сказуемыми (хотя и с разными типами) или сложносочиненнЫм.

> Предложения с разнооформленными сказуемыми (глагольные и именные) чаще
>   всего считают не простыми с однородными сказуемыми, а сложными с
>   односоставными простыми, следовательно, запятая нужна. Это переходный
>   тип предложений, автор вправе выбрать, какими их считать и ставить ли
>   запятую. –

(Людмила)

Лучше не скажешь. Поскольку комментарии стали часто удаляться в чат, воспроизвожу как цитату.

Вообще спор здесь "на тоненького". В грамматике любого естественного языка есть случаи неформализуемости. В частности, бывает,  что некоторая фраза априори не может быть разобрана синтаксически однозначно, даже с учетом контекста. Вот это наш пример. Можете назвать это семантико-синтаксической омонимией. И в таких случаях действительно можно прибегнуть к какому-то статистическому анализу. Но ведь есть еще и принцип бритвы Оккама, который в вульгарном (но от того не менее жизненном) переложении звучит как "что проще - то и правильно". Здесь, видимо, "проще" считать фразу простой, осложненной однородными сказуемыми, а не сложносочиненной. Почему так, сказать трудно, тем более что это понятие "проще" здесь субъективно. Главное при это: не употреблять слово "надо" на основании такого статистического анализа или собственного мнения. Потому что здесь максимум "предпочтительно".

Чтобы закрыть вопрос. "Я ранняя пташка и всегда встаю чуть свет" и "Я ранняя пташка, и всегда встаю с хорошим настроением" я субъективно рассматриваю как предложения разной структуры. Без учета этих тонкостей разговоры о обязательности/невозможности запятой вообще считаю некорректными. Только рекомендательно.

> http://scicenter.online/sintaksis/odnorodnyie-glavnyie-chlenyi-126266.html

(Людмила)

Это вообще-то Валгина...